# Change value in class with variable from For loop

Tags: swift, class

I have the following question about swift, let say I have an class like so:

```
class Person {
    var firstName, lastName, eyeColor: String

    init(firstName: String = "", lastName: String = "", eyeColor: String = "") {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.eyeColor = eyeColor
    }
}
```

I could for example create a person like so:

```
var myFriend = Person(firstName: "Robin", eyeColor: "Yellow")
```

However as you can tell now I have not assigned a value to lastName aka this will be empty or "".

What I want to do is iterate over all values in myFriend and check if one is empty, if thats true I would like it to replace the empty value with something like "No information".

I did find something like

```
    let mirroredRecord = Mirror(reflecting: myFriend)
    for (index, attr) in mirroredRecord.children.enumerated() {
        if var value = attr.label as String? {
            if value == "" {
                value = "No info"
            }
            print("Attr \(index): \(value) = \(attr.value)")
        }
    }
```

However that does not change the value in the myFriend variable.

In my head the following seems logical but i'm unsure how to perform this action in swift.

```
for (index, attr) in mirroredRecord.children.enumerated() {
    if var value = attr.label as String? {
        if value == "" {
            myFriend.value = "No info"
        }
        print("Attr \(index): \(value) = \(attr.value)")
    }
}
```

However because .value is not one of the options (firstName, lastName, eyeColor) it doesn't like it.

Does anyone have any options or solutions regarding this?

Comment: How about assigning `"No Information"` as default value? `init(firstName: String = "No Information", lastName: String = "No Information", eyeColor: String = "No Information") {`

Comment: I thought of this, however in my case I want to be able to show these fields in labels, and so I prefer the label to show empty instead of "no info" what I could do of course is have some kind of logic where if the value is "no info" put "" in the label but it would be a lot of checking for this.

Comment: Alternatively declare the properties as optional which can be empty.

Comment: This would be a total misuse of both `String` and `Mirror`. This is precisely what optionals are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `class` with a `for` loop if you use `KeyPath`s to represent the fields you want to update:

```
func update() {
    let kpaths: [ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Person, String>] = [\.firstName, \.lastName, \.eyeColor]

    for path in kpaths {
        if self[keyPath: path].isEmpty {
            self[keyPath: path] = "No information"
        }
    }
}
```

---

That said, I would suggest just using *optionals* with `nil` representing `"No Information"`.

```
class Person {
    var firstName, lastName, eyeColor: String?

    init(firstName: String? = nil, lastName: String? = nil, eyeColor: String? = nil) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.eyeColor = eyeColor
    }
}
```

Then when you access the fields, you can use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to unwrap the value and present `nil` ones however you like:

```
someLabel.text = self.firstName ?? ""
```

**or:**

```
someLabel.text = self.firstName ?? "No information"
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up providing these values nil instead of "" then indeed in a later stage provide them the "No information" label!